# To plot chart based on dynamic user ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

The aim is to plot the values against `column A` (X-axis). The user selects a column name in cell `G4`, the values of `G4` could be `B`,`C`,`C`,`D`. Based on the column name a chart has to be plotted.

[image]

I was able to write the following code which selects the data but I cannot select the data dynamically.

```
Sub Chart()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim TimeAxis As Range
Dim Values As Range
Dim cht As Object

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
TimeAxis = Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).Select '<----- X Axis (Static) 
Values = Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).Select  '<----- User selected as per cell G4 (Dynamic)     

'Plot TimeAxis Vs Values

Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng    '<------ User Range (Dynamic)
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that row counting variables must be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim Lastrow As Long`. I recommend [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA since there is no benefit in `Integer` at all.

You must use `Set TimeAxis` (because ranges are objects) and remove the `.Select`. Also see
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Finally `Set` your `rng` otherwise it is empty and you cannot use it in `Source:=rng`.

So you end up with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateChart() 'dont use "chart" as procedure name it is a type in VBA and therefore a reserved word
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim TimeAxis As Range
    Set TimeAxis = Range("A2:A" & LastRow) 'X Axis values start at A2!!!

    Dim SelCol As String
    SelCol = ActiveSheet.Range("G4") 'read column name from G4

    Dim Values As Range
    Set Values = Range(SelCol & "1:" & SelCol & LastRow)  '<----- User selected as per cell G4 (Dynamic)

    'Plot TimeAxis Vs Values

    Dim cht As Object
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
    cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Values    '<------ User Range (Dynamic)
    cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = TimeAxis 'x axis values
    cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
End Sub
```

Comment: On line `Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2` it gives the following error `Run-time error '438': Object does not support this property or method` therefore I changed the line to `Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart` but now it shows the same error on line `cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = TimeAxis 'x axis values`

Comment: I tested it and it worked in my Excel version. Try to use `SeriesCollection(1)` instead.